# telethon how to request call with code for login

Tags: telethon

Since I am writing a client, my friends from the USA noticed that the code does not go through SMS, but only through a call. but I don’t understand how to do it, how to request a call(

```
 await client.connect()


    code_settings = types.CodeSettings(
        current_number=True,
        allow_flashcall=False,
        allow_app_hash=False
    )
    result = await client(functions.auth.SendCodeRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        api_id=api_id,
        api_hash=api_hash,
        settings=code_settings
    ))
    # time.sleep(10)
    result = await client(functions.auth.ResendCodeRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        phone_code_hash=result.phone_code_hash
    ))
    # time.sleep(20)
    result = await client(functions.auth.ResendCodeRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        phone_code_hash=result.phone_code_hash
    ))

    # result = await client(SentCodeTypeCall(5))
    # result = await client(functions.auth.)

    while not isinstance(result.type, SentCodeTypeCall):
        # time.sleep(10)
        result = await client(functions.auth.ResendCodeRequest(
            phone_number=phone,
            phone_code_hash=result.phone_code_hash
        ))
    # time.sleep(20)
    # await client(functions.auth.SendCodeRequest(
    #     phone_number=phone,
    #     api_id=api_id,
    #     api_hash=api_hash,
    #     settings=code_settings
    # ))

    def code_callback():
        code = input('Please enter the code you received: ')
        return code

    time.sleep(5)
    await client.start(phone=phone, code_callback=code_callback)
```

I assume this is not the correct code.

can I tell the SendCode Request method to call immediately without sending SMS?

Comment: @Lonami is there some example code where the method of receiving a code through a call is shown?

Comment: I don't have knowledge on calls to auth, I've never used them (and never cared to try). Raw API like you're doing should be the way to go, but I have no idea on the required sequence.

Comment: Do you have friends who made a client in telethon?) who used the authorization functions through the phone call